# Comparing String with String from file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
data = File.read("data.txt")
if(data.to_s.eql? "hello")
  ...   
end
```

My data.txt is filled with "hello" as well, so the if-loop should get active but it doesn't. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Your data from the file likely includes a trailing newline character. Do `p data` and you'll see.

Comment: Also, style-wise, your parenthesizing is... unusual. Either do `if data.to_s.eql?("hello")` (what I would do) or no parentheses at all (they're not necessary here)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you _would do_ `String#to_s#eql?`?!

Comment: @mudasobwa: you know what I meant. :) The comment was only about parentheses. Fixing other issues is out of scope.

Comment: `data.chomp.eql? "hello" #=> true`

Comment: Try with `data.include?('hello')` if you **instead** want to check `data` contains a particular string. Ignore otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading data from a file, it's likely you get a newline tagged on to the end of your data.

For example, if I run the following in the terminal to create a file containing only the word 'hello':

```
echo hello > data.txt
```

And the read this in the terminal, I see:

```
cat data.txt
# => hello
```

However, jumping into `irb`, I get the following:

```
File.read("data.txt")
# => "hello\n"
```

The `\n` is the newline operator.

To solve your question, you can use:

```
if data.chomp == "hello"
  ...   
end
```

[`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) removes any record separator from the end of the string, giving you the comparison you're after.

If you just want to know whether the file contains the specified string, you can also use:

```
data['hello']
```

This will return the truthy value in the square brackets if present, or `nil` if not.

```
if data["hello"]
  ...   
end
```

Comment: Touching the file is not necessary, btw. At least, on my machine.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, not necessary anywhere(Ubuntu, Windows etc)